# how to delete a google calendar event?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I write an android app that fetches my events,

How can I identify an event (some unique ID)
and delete it or edit it?

```
private void fetchEvents() {
    String[] selection = new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
            "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" };

    String projection = "description LIKE ?";
    String[] selecionArgs = new String[]{"%/images/%"};
    String orderby = "dtstart ASC";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(
                    Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                    selection, projection,
                    selecionArgs, orderby);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // fetching calendars name
    String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    // fetching calendars id
    nameOfEvent.clear();
    startDates.clear();
    endDates.clear();
    descriptions.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
        nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
        startDates.add(new Date(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
        //endDates.add(new Date(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));

        String fullDescription = cursor.getString(2);

        int firstIndex = fullDescription.indexOf("localUri: ");
        firstIndex = (firstIndex < 0)? 0 : 10;


        int lastIndex = fullDescription.indexOf("\n");
        lastIndex = (lastIndex < 0)? fullDescription.length() : lastIndex;

        descriptions.add(fullDescription.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex));

        CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `google-app-engine`?

Comment: thought it was Google client API